# How can I retrieve a (quasi) Array from a URL string?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I would like to achieve something I can easily do in .net.

What I would like to do is pass multiple URL parameters of the same name to build an array of those values.

In other words, I would like to take a URL string like so:

```
http://www.example.com/Test.cfc?method=myArrayTest&foo=1&foo=2&foo=3
```

And build an array from the URL parameter "foo".

In .net / C# I can do something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
myArrayTest(string[] foo)
```

And that will build a string array from the variable "foo".

What I have done so far is something like this:

```
<cffunction name="myArrayTest" access="remote" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="foo" type="string" required="yes">
```

This would output:

```
1,2,3
```

I'm not thrilled with that because it's just a comma separated string and I'm afraid that there may be commas passed in the URL (encoded of course) and then if I try to loop over the commas it may be misinterpreted as a separate param.

So, I'm stumped on how to achieve this.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you need to parse the current URL or arbitrary URL's?

Comment: It's kindof neither.. I'm creating a Web Service via a CFC and using a function within the CFC to pull off the URL params which I am then using to, hopefully, loop through (no modifying involved, just reading). EDIT: it's a RESTful web service, so I'm posting data to it via just a URL and not a SOAP-like XML post.

Comment: Well if you are "pull[ing] off the url params" then it sounds like you are parsing the current url. So a `cfdump` of `#URL#` or `#CGI.QUERY_STRING#` within the cfc would show the "foo" parameters, correct?

Comment: You're right, my apologies, I am parsing the curent URL.  If I dump the URL using either method you mentioned I do see all of the "foo" params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're OK with parsing the URL, following "raw" method may work for you:

```
<cffunction name="myArrayTest" access="remote" output="false">

    <cfset var local = {} />

    <!--- parse raw query --->
    <cfset local.args = ListToArray(cgi.QUERY_STRING, "&") />

    <!--- grab only foo's values --->
    <cfset local.foo = [] />
    <cfloop array="#local.args#" index="local.a">
        <cfif Left(local.a, 3) EQ "foo">
            <cfset ArrayAppend(local.foo, ListLast(local.a, "=")) />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn SerializeJSON(local.foo) />

</cffunction>
```

I've tested it with this query: `?method=myArrayTest&foo=1&foo=2&foo=3,3`, looks to work as expected.

Bonus. Railo's top tip: if you format the query as follows, this array will be created automatically in URL scope `?method=myArrayTest&foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3,3`.

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thanks for the bonus tip too btw.  Unfortunately, one of the client applications written in Java doesn't like it when I use square brackets in the URL, so for now I am going to use your original post, but thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Sergii's method is more versatile. But if you are parsing the current url, and do *not* need to modify the resulting array, another option is using [getPageContext()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-787f.html) to extract the parameter from the underlying request. Just be aware of the two quirks noted below.

```
<!--- note: duplicate forces the map to be case-INsensitive --->
<cfset params = duplicate(getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap())>
<cfset quasiArray = []>
<cfif structKeyExists(params, "foo")>
    <!--- note: this is not a *true* CF array --->
    <!--- you can do most things with it, but you cannot append data to it --->
    <cfset quasiArray = params["foo"]>
</cfif>
<cfdump var="#quasiArray#">
```

Answer (score 0):

`listToArray( arguments.foo )` should give you what you want.

Comment: Yes, but he mentioned the values might contain commas. listToArray would treat the single value "a,b" as separate values.

Comment: Good point. This is one time where ColdFusion automatically decoding URL encoded values can cause issues.